# How to get parent names in git's prepare-commit-msg hook

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

When creating your own git hook for prepare-commit-msg, how can you determine the list of parents?

It's not included in the args passed in.  Is there possibly a git command to run on the cli that will tell you the parents of an in-progress merge?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to to get the incoming branch via a couple git commands.  Here's the python code for the prepare-commit-msg

```
import sys, os, re
from subprocess import check_output

# Collect the parameters
commit_msg_filepath = sys.argv[1]
commit_source = sys.argv[2]

# Figure out which branch we're on
branch = check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD']).decode('ascii').strip()
print ("prepare-commit-msg: On branch '" + branch + "' from source '" + commit_source +"'")

foreignCommitHash = check_output(['cat', '.git/MERGE_HEAD']).decode('ascii').strip()
print (foreignCommitHash)

branch2 = check_output(['git', 'branch', '--contains', foreignCommitHash]).decode('ascii').strip()
print (branch2)
```